# Importing a class from a c# dll into a c++ app

Tags: c#, c++, dll, v8, node-gyp

I need to import a dll made in c# from c++
All the examples I found import a single function from a dll, but as far as I know, you cannot export a single function from c# without exporting the whole class (I'm a bit of a c# newbie though)

I am using node gyp to compile it (I'm building a node module for my web app using v8)

Here is my c# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Hello 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        string createText = "Hello World" + Environment.NewLine;
        File.WriteAllText(".\\asd.txt", createText);
    }
}
```

And this is my c++ header file:

```cpp
#ifndef ASDLIB_H
#define ASDLIB_H
#define ASD_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#define STDCALL __stdcall

class ASD_IMPORT Hello{
    public:
         STDCALL static void ASD_IMPORT Main();
};

#endif // ASDLIB_H
```

Comment: Taking advantage of a [ComVisible] C# class requires [writing COM code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp).  Have a look at the UnmanagedExports nuget package, okayish for simple functions like this.

Comment: In your case you're trying to make application (.exe) exported. I'm not sure this is really what you want to do. Normally one would create a c# library and export that. I also dont like COM. I've provided you an example with CLR wrapping, what I normally use occasionaly when I need this kind of conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally do this kind of stuff by creating a static C++ CLR Wrapper Lib.

These are the steps I'm normally using (although I don't use it very often):

Here minimal example with using Visual Studio:

**1. Create managed C# .NET library Project**

Let name it **HelloLibManaged** 
   with one file **Hello.cs** and following content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelloLibManaged
{
    public class Hello
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello from Managed Lib");
        }
    }
}
```

**Build this lib with x86 or x64** , just dont Any CPU

**2. Create a new C++ CLR static lib project** within same solution.
   Let's name it **HelloLibCpp**

- Add a reference to **HelloLibManaged** project via Project->Add Reference
- Remove automatic created existing .h/.cpp files from Project, and create these 2 files:

**HelloUnmanaged.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace hello_managed {

    class Hello
    {
    public:
        void Print();
    };
}
```

and

**HelloUnmanaged.cpp**:

```
#include "HelloUnmanaged.h"

namespace hello_managed
{

    void Hello::Print()
    {
        HelloLibManaged::Hello^ hello = gcnew HelloLibManaged::Hello();
        hello->Print();
    }

}
```

Und Project Properties -> General  specify static lib.
In the **Build settings specify x86 / x64** - use the **same build type as building Managed lib from Step 1.**

Now you can build the dll and use it in your other unmanaged C++ projects.

For more advanced stuff, like return types and methods with parameters you have to do Type-Marshalling between managed/unmanaged code. There are many resources online with more information about Type-Conversion between managed/unmanaged code. Keyword: **Marshaling**.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try this. What compiler / IDE are you using?

Comment: For this example VS 2017

Comment: Cool! I tried it out and it worked
Also, searching for Marshaling, I came across the edge.js node module, which would allow me to use my c# dll directly from js
Thanks for your help!